# Using Recursion to Replace all occurences of a substring with another substring

Tags: string, recursion, python-3.x, substring

Given an string and two of its substrings (named a and b) I need to write a recursive function that replace all occurrences of b with a and then returns the new string.

Could someone help me how to begin?

Comment: Recursive in what sense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recursively you know that your function applied to:

- base case)  An empty string, must return an empty string;
- rec case)   A string starting with `b`, must replace `b` with `a` and check the rest of the string;
- rec case)   Else, return the first character of the string chained to rest of the string returned recursively

Here is the algorithm:

```
def rec_replace(string, a, b):
    if not string: #if the string is empty
        return ""
    elif string[:len(b)] == b: #if the string start with b, replace it with a
        return a + rec_replace(string[len(b):], a, b)
    else: #else, add this character and go to the next one
        return string[0] + rec_replace(string[1:], a, b)
```

Test:

```
print rec_replace("hello this is hello a simple hello test", "ok", "hello")
```

Output:

```
ok this is ok a simple ok test
```